# dynamic sort type doesn't work in mybatis

Tags: mybatis

I couldn't create SQL in mybatis using dynamic sort type as the following example

```
<select id="selectByNetworkId" parameterType="java.util.Map" resultMap="userResult">

    select user_profile.user_profile_id,  user_profile.first_name
    from
    user_profile user_profile

    where
    user_profile.network_id = #{network_id}  

    order by
    user_profile.user_profile.first_name #{sortType}        
</select>
```

the sortType holds one value of {DESC, ASC}, and I got the following error when calling this SQL from my dao

#### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

any idea?

Comment: would you mind posting the  userResult map?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try ${sortType}. For direct substitution, use ${}.

Comment: Note that you must validate anything included with a dollar sign to avoid swell injection